# discord.py , help command wont be disabled and still works

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

im trying to disable the `help` and create my own `help` but no matter how many times i tried , it didnt work

i tried `client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "$",help_command=None , intents = discord.Intents.all())` and tried `client.remove_command('help')` aswell but still no result and `help` still works

**MY CODE :**

```
@client.command()
async def help(ctx):
    
    emb = discord.Embed(description='⚠️ This Command doesnt work ,Try $helpme', color=0x0d67d6)
    await ctx.channel.send(embed=emb)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=',', intents=intents)

You also have to enable privileged intents in the developer portal - https://discord.com/developers/applications

Comment: i changed `intents = discord.Intents.all()` to `intents = discord.Intents.default()` as you told me but still didnt work